# wsgen 'Class not found'

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsgen

This is the setup of my java project

[image]

I'm trying to run wsgen through cmd:

`wsgen -keep -cp . com.library.webservice.HelloWorldImplementation`

But I'm getting the error

`Class not found: "com.library.webservice.HelloWorldImplementation"`

Also, the command is running from `C:\ ... \WebServices Test\src`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`C:\ ... \WebServices Test\src` contains the Java source files, not the class files. The classpath specified via `-cp` should point to the directory that contains the compiled classes, typically the `bin` folder. Therefore you should run the command from that directory.